# Error authentication from API in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt, asp.net-identity

My solution has are 4 projects:

- ASP.NET Web Api
- ASP.NET MVC
- Services (here I implementing using interfaces the actions for the API, including login and register)
- Domain (model classes)

In the API project, everything works, but when I include the login in MVC project I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)

I using the JWT authentication and IdentityUser. When I debug the login in the MVC project, the token is returned, but when the view with `Authorize` is opened, I get the error. Can someone help me?

Code for login in my controller in the MVC project:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Usuarios usuarios)
{
     using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
     {
         StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usuarios), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:xxxx/api/Usuarios/Login", stringContent))
                {
                    string token = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (token == "Invalid credentials")
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "Incorrect UserId or Password!";
                        return Redirect("~/Usuarios/Login");
                    }

                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("JWToken", token);
                }

                return Redirect("~/ProfileUsers/UserProfile");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method `Login` in your APS.NET MVC project and indicate the claims' date for your identity user.